# Node.js fails to start with v8 symbol error

Tags: centos, node.js, v8

I installed the nodejs package on CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

But it crashed on startup when run with no arguments:

```
[root@lcnolw1073 ~]# nodejs

    nodejs: ../src/handle_wrap.cc:65: static v8::Handle<v8::Value> node::HandleWrap::Unref(const v8::Arguments&): Assertion `args.Holder()->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

And also with an empty file:

```
[root@lcnolw1073 ~]# nodejs /dev/null
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either the version of Node.js, in whatever repo you're getting it from, is broken, or something went very badly wrong during installation, and yum failed to catch the error.

In either case, I'd recommend uninstalling the package, then cleaning out the yum cache with `yum clean`, and finally reinstalling to see whether the error persists; if it does, I'd uninstall the package again and then build Node.js from source, which you can find [here](http://nodejs.org/download/). (It's not all that hard to build Node from source; I did so just the other day, on Cygwin, yet, and all it required was the usual `configure && make && make install` invocation.)

Comment: How to remove nodejs from CentOS 6.3? Write commands please.

Comment: @BobSmith That depends entirely on **how you installed it**. Since you didn't tell us how you installed it, we can't tell you how to remove it.